# Error connecting mysql on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I was deploying a Rails application with mysql on Ubuntu, when I run `rake db:migrate`, I got the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'`.

By the way, I installed mysql by apt-get.

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer on this page http://www.davideisinger.com/article/getting-started-with-ubuntu

> This last step is just for Ruby on Rails. For whatever reason, Ubuntu puts the mysql.sock file in a different place than most Linux distros, confusing Rails. In order to point it to the correct place, create the following symlink:

`ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`

because your default database.yml in your application wrote this `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock`